# Trying to convert jquery ajax to angular http

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, http

I want to convert my previous mobile application from jquery ajax to angularjs. It is mostly about authenticating user credentials using server-side validation.

jquery ajax:

```
function validateStaffUser(username, password) {
    var request = {
        request: {
            Password: password,
            Username: username
        }
     };
    var jsondata = JSON.stringify(request);


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url_authenticate+ "ValidateStaff",
        data: jsondata,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            var valid = handleValidateStaffError(response);

            if(valid == false)
                return;

            localStorage.UserId = response.UserId;
            $.mobile.changePage(firstPage);
        },
        error: function(msg) {
            error();
        }
    });
}
```

angular js codes:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $http, $ionicPopup, $state) {
            $scope.myData = {};
            $scope.validateStaffUser = function($scope.data.username,$scope.data.password) {

            $http({
            var request = {
                    request: {
                            Username:username,
                            Password: password
                  }
            };
            var jsondata = JSON.stringify(request);
            type: "POST",
            url: url_authenticate+ "ValidateStaff",
            data: jsondata,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
      }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $state.go('tab.firstPage');
      }).error(function(msg) {
             var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                 title: 'Login failed!',
                 template: 'Please check your credentials!'
      });
          }
      });
```

However I always obtain the error message. Can someone help me?

Comment: go through this doc https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: You should not use JSON.stringify

Comment: You are declaring variables using var inside your object definition. That'll cause a problem.

Comment: try to use $resource instead of $http.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this "pattern" to build up $http post requests.

```
$http.post("url", {jsonObjectToPost}).then(function(successData){
//do something
}, function(error){
//do something
});
```

Comment: where should I put my requests?

Comment: first argument: url, second argument: an json object where you should put your data so the server can get the request and do something with it.